# IdentityServer4 "Unknown location" when redirecting to client

Tags: c#, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer application as an external provider. After redirecting from IdentityServer back to my application I am getting "500 unable to unprotect message state. Unknown location". But if I refresh page, I am signed in.

I added logs to requests and all cookies are passed in both requests. For me they look identical. But for some reason redirect doesn't work, but refresh request works

Comment: sounds like a cookie problem, I blogged about troubelshooting cookie issues at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/